# laravel 5.1 installation issue with php 7.1 , cannot install carbon 2

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, php-carbon, php-7.1

- composer install error on  carbon 1 is deprecated
  SO, how can i run my vagrant with laravel 5.1 with carbon 1  and I have try find from stackoverflow and other site but no helps comes up .
  every thing is done but shows carbon 1 is deprecated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://carbon.nesbot.com/

You can install Carbon 2:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "2.64.0 as 1.39.0"
        "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

But such an old stack will gives you so much trouble. Laravel 5.1 and PHP 7.1 are both in end of life (no longer maintained). You should upgrade the whole stack. At this point having Carbon 1 would make little difference. If you're fine with having old stuff, no longer matching their documentation, then you can ignore deprecation notices.

Comment: I need to use composer 1 with carbon 1 ,So i use carbon 2 then need to update other dependency file which is not possible

Comment: "I need to use composer 1 with carbon 1" =>

No you don't, Carbon 1.39.1 can be installed with both Composer 1 or 2.

If you fall in an impossible installation situation, you should question each of the constraint/choice leading here. Why not updating PHP? Composer? Laravel? And then Carbon is just a minor detail in the picture. If not wanting to update any of those, why trying to update anything at all and not just stick with the last composer.lock install? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`